# ActiveRecord map count of whole collection, then that query to SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I write this query in SQL?

```
a = Brand.find(1).publications.map(&:component_id)
Hash[a.group_by(&:itself).map {|k, v| [Component.find(k).name, v.size] }]

=> {"title one"=>1, "something"=>1, "continue"=>1}
```

Obviously I can't call `.to_sql` on `Ennumerable`. I've written this so far, but it seems to be counting something other than the number of occurrences:

```
SELECT c.name, c.id, COUNT(p.component_id)
FROM publications p
INNER JOIN components c 
ON c.id = p.component_id 
INNER JOIN brands_components bc
ON bc.brand_id IN (1)
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

This gets the wrong numbers (i.e., too many are identical):

```
name             id      count
------------------------------
something        2026    114
another name     3028    1,140
another new one  2409    2,850
world class      264     6,612
top up           3370    114
```

The model associations look like this:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents
  has_many :publications, through: :users
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :publications, through: :documents, dependent: :destroy
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :brand

  has_many :components, through: :publications
  has_many :publications, dependent: :destroy
end

class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document
  belongs_to :component
end

class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :publications
  has_many :documents, through: :publications
end
```

I want to return the count of occurrences of `component_id` on `Publication` filtered by `Brand` in SQL.

Comment: so `Brand` has_many `Users`,  `User` has_many `Documents`, and `Document` has_many `Components`, through `Publication`.  And you want to do a count of all the Components on a Brand?

Comment: Please post the model relations and say what is the data you need back

Comment: Code has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my issue:

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(p.component_id)
FROM publications p
INNER JOIN components c 
ON c.id = p.component_id 
INNER JOIN brands_components bc
ON c.id = bc.component_id
AND bc.brand_id IN (1)
GROUP BY 1
```

I had forgotten to make this match: `c.id = bc.component_id`. Might help someone.